# Simple PHP DOM Parser adds unwanted spaces in plaintext

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser to extract cell values content off an HTML table and store them in an array.

**HTML**:

```
<td class="inflexion">so<span class="deviation">y</span></td>
<td class="inflexion"><span class="deviation">fui</span></td>
<td class="inflexion"><span class="deviation">er</span>a</td>
<td class="inflexion">haber sería</td>
```

**Desired output**:

> soy
>
> fui
>
> era
>
> haber sería

**PHP**:

```
function getvariations($conjtables){
    $conjtables = str_get_html($conjtables);
    $variations = [];
    foreach ($conjtables->find('td[class=inflexion]') as $inflexion) {
        $variations[] = $inflexion->plaintext;
    }
    return array_unique($variations);
}
$variations = getvariations($conjtables);
foreach ($variations as $variation) {
    echo $variation . '<br>';
}
```

This works, however, the output seems to prepend some occurrences of the span element with an undesired space (see third item below):

> soy
>
> fui
>
> er a
>
> haber sería

Any suggestions around fixing this? I cannot remove spaces arbitrarily because some cells happen to genuinely have multiple words as in the last item in the example given.

Comment: Get value from inner `span` and after it and implode'em

Comment: Did you see that the `a` of `er a` is outside the `span`. Add some css rules like `.deviation {margin:0;padding:0;}` or move the `a` into the `span`!

Comment: "a" is outside the <span> by design and I cannot change that. I need the values for the purpose of storing them in a MySQL table, so changing CSS is not much help.

Comment: There are no real spaces (see first HTML block from you), it seems that css rules are adding this space. Use Browser Developing Console to check if its real space or some padding/margin.

Comment: There's no CSS rule adding any space there. The .deviation span is only for the purpose of color coding.

Comment: Besides, margin/padding settings, although not any, should have no bearing on what the DOM parser sees as innertext values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `innertext` with [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) instead of `plaintext`:

```
function getvariations($conjtables){
    $conjtables = str_get_html($conjtables);
    $variations = [];
    foreach ($conjtables->find('td[class=inflexion]') as $inflexion) {
        $variations[] = strip_tags($inflexion->innertext);
    }
    return array_unique($variations);
}
$variations = getvariations($conjtables);
foreach ($variations as $variation) {
    echo $variation . '<br>';
}
```

Output:

> soy
>
> fui
>
> era
>
> haber sería

Comment: Only problem is that it preserves the tags which I don't want. For example, instead of giving **era**, it returns **<span class="deviation">er</span>a**.

Comment: Never mind. strip_tags() is what did it for me. Thanks!